# The first two columns defined as "rownames"

Tags: r, tibble, r-rownames

I want to define the first two columns of a data frame as rownames. Actually I want to do some calculations and the data frame has to be numeric for that.

```
data.frame <- data_frame(id=c("A1","B2"),name=c("julia","daniel"),BMI=c("20","49"))
```

The values for BMI are numerical (proved with is.numeric), but the over all data.frame not. How to define the first two columns (id and name) as rownames?
Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Please do not name your variables as a function names: avoid using `data.frame <- `

Comment: You can't set a rowname on a tibble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `id` and `name` column and then assign rownames

```
data.frame %>%
  tidyr::unite(rowname, id, name) %>%
  tibble::column_to_rownames()

#          BMI
#A1_julia   20
#B2_daniel  49
```

---

In base R, you can do the same in steps as

```
data.frame <- as.data.frame(data.frame)
rownames(data.frame) <- paste(data.frame$id, data.frame$name, sep = "_")
data.frame[c('id', 'name')] <- NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the code and result below is the thing you are after:

```
dfout <- `rownames<-`(data.frame(BMI = as.numeric(df$BMI)),paste(df$id,df$name))
```

such that

```
> dfout
          BMI
A1 julia   20
B2 daniel  49
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(id = structure(1:2, .Label = c("A1", "B2"), class = "factor"), 
    name = structure(2:1, .Label = c("daniel", "julia"), class = "factor"), 
    BMI = structure(1:2, .Label = c("20", "49"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Then this occurs: Error in df[3] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @takeITeasy Did you use the `df` from my answer? Also, I updated my answer so you can try it again

Comment: actually my real dataset is much bigger than the example I posted in the question. Is there any way to do it without having to type in everything manually? But I really thank you for your answer ;)